# Looking for faucet handle

Tags: plumbing-fixture

[image]
Looking for lever handle for old Briggs shower faucet as per picture attached.  Acrylic part has cracked so just glued and put elastic band around to hold together

Comment: How about a picture from the top?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.